# How to create a modal navigation menu on mobile and prevent body scrolling?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, scroll, modal-dialog

I looked for and tested many solutions but I can't make it work yet. I want the subnavigation menu (modal) be able to scroll when showed, but not the body.

I tried :

1 : Javascript changing CSS property to "fixed" when modal open:

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed;");
```

**Problem :** If you are scrolling the page when you open the modal, the page goes up (as "fixed" also means you can't have a scroll bar)

2 : Javascript changing CSS property to "overflow hidden" when modal open :

```
document.body.setAttribute("style", "overflow: hidden;");
```

**Problem :** Doesn't work on mobile, still scrolls (I use android).

3 : Javascript disabling touch events :

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
main.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ e.preventDefault();});
main.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault();});
```

**Problem :** Works except if you start touching from within the subnavigation menu.

See this to understand better what I mean : http://i45.tinypic.com/ajl3rt.png

Then, how to prevent the body scrolling in a mobile device when an overlay menu is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Typically overflow:hidden accomplishes this on desktop. For mobile you'll also need to apply position fixed. So, when your dialog is active, add a ".noscroll" class to the body:

```
body.noscroll{
overflow:hidden;
position:fixed;
}
```